# Scanner class is skipping lines

Tags: java

I'm new to programing and I'm having a problem with my scanner class. This code is in a loop and when the loop comes around the second, third whatever time I have it set to it skips the first title input.
I need help please why is it skipping my title scanner input in the beginning?

```
System.out.println("Title:");

list[i].title=keyboard.nextLine();

System.out.println("Author:");

list[i].author=keyboard.nextLine();

System.out.println("Album:");

list[i].album=keyboard.nextLine();

System.out.println("Filename:");

list[i].filename=keyboard.nextLine();
```

Comment: Can you post the complete code?

Comment: What do you mean by "skips"? Where does this code reside? Give us a bit of [sample code](http://sscce.org/) to run that displays the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It is likely that, in the code you haven't shown us, there exists a call to one of `Scanner` input methods that does not consume a newline method. `nextLine` for example. In this instance the newline character will be passed from the end of the loop to the subsequent `nextLine` statement. This now will not block having received input. The solution is to ensure the newline is consumed at the end of each iteration

```
// list[i].id = keyboard.nextInt();
list[i].id = Integer.parseInt(keyboard.nextLine());
```

Comment: Yea you are right that is only part of the code! The last line of the code is a nextInt();

Comment: What I have learned is that when you have a line of scanner for example

Comment: What I have learned is that when you have a line of scanner for example keyboard.nextLine(); and then keyboard.nextInt();  The computer stores the scanned in string and it also is ready for the next iteration, but after the Scanned in Int the computer does not finish the iteration until the nextLine statement. So whenever there is an Int it need to be nextLIned before you can enter the next piece of information in the Scanner. The String does not need to be nextLined it does it automatically.